# iOs Twitter signin (Swift) Error obtaining user auth token. error: Request failed: forbidden (403)

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login with twitter in my application, but I am getting an error

```
FirebaseProject[9536:57007] [TwitterKit]
Error obtaining user auth token.
error: Request failed: forbidden (403)
```

[image: Console log]

**and my info.plist**

[image: info.plist]

**and AppDelegate.swift**

```
     func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
       return TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval:3)
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"4-----L", consumerSecret:"bc----------------------b")
```

unable to find, what wrong with me.

Comment: Don't post images of code or errors. Paste them as text.

Comment: code added, please check

Comment: did you find any solution..i am facing the same problem